# Node.JS Readline not accepting inputs

Tags: node.js, readline

I have code below that should prompt the user for their age and you type in the age and it should return with `You entered: 9` and exit the program. Originally, it worked in VSCode, and then it stopped working. Then I tried in Windows Terminal, it worked a few times and then it didn't allow me to type anything because it closes immediately after running. However, I tried using repl.it to see if the same thing would happen, and it doesn't. And repl.it works as expected all the time.

My repl: https://replit.com/@DrakeSemchyshyn/TameWordySort

Node Version: v18.14.0

OS: Windows 11 Insider Preview 25336.1000 (rs_prerelease)

```js
import readline from "readline";

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.openStdin(),
  output: process.stdout,
});

rl.on("line", (age) => {
  console.log(`You entered: ${age}`);
  console.log("Goodbye!");
  setTimeout(() => {
    rl.close();
  }, 10);
});

rl.setPrompt(`What is your age? `);
rl.resume();
rl.prompt();
```

I don't know why this quirky behavior acts as it does. Thank you for reading this and trying to help me.

Comment: did you try prompt-sync package instead ?